# Override Surefire configuration through command line

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I think this is a simple problem for a Java DevOps. I have problems with the Surefire parameter which sets the number of test execution threads.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <forkCount>2.5C</forkCount>
      <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I wish I could specify an override from the command line to set it to `1`.

Comment: ist kind of Java related Devops so Java experts might not even know.

Comment: In short - it it is possible to specify it in <configuration> that the same can be set via CLI. Check configuration options then.

Comment: seems to be not possible. Except the configuration way :(

Comment: if it is possible configuration way, you can do the same from CLI.

Comment: I encountered issue with CPU usage at 100% when running Maven package for a project. In the POM, forkCount of 4 was specified for the surefire plugin. No matter what command line options I passed, it was always launching 4 JVM processes and CPU usage reached 100%. I didn't find any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the goals of a plugin at the [*Goals* page](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/plugin-info.html) of every Maven plugin. If you select a specific goal there you see the [goal's parameters](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) and for the `surefire:test` goal there is:

> `<forkCount>` ... **User property is:** [What a surprise! ;] `forkCount`

Hence:

```
mvn ... -DforkCount=1 ...
```